# Calculate standard deviation of lowest N values in a column

Tags: r, ranking

How do I calculate the standard deviation of the lowest N values in a dataset?

For example, using the `mtcars` dataset, how would I do this for, say, `hp`?  Note that it may need to be performed on multiple columns so I am looking for a generalized process.

`sd(mtcars$hp)` # of smallest 5 values.

Comment: `sd(sort(mtcars$hp)[1:5])`

Comment: `sd(head(mtcars$hp[order(mtcars$hp)], 5))`

Comment: `sd(head(sort.int(mtcars$hp, partial = 1:5), 5))` for max efficiency

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you tagged dplyr, so here is a dplyr way to do it:

Just cyl and mpg:
`summarise_each(mtcars, funs(sd(sort(.)[1:5])), cyl, mpg)`

All columns:
    `summarise_each(mtcars, funs(sd(sort(.)[1:5])))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get standard deviation of lowest n values of each column, you can do the following:

```
sapply(mtcars, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sd(sort(x)[1:5]))
```

If you want to do it for top 5 values of each column, you can do the following:

```
sapply(mtcars, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sd(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]))
```

If you want to do it for select columns only, you can do this:

```
sapply(mtcars[, c('mpg', 'wt', 'hp')], function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sd(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]))
```